# How to use gin with go-elasticsearch?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, frameworks

Using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for API.

Its route.go

```
func Init(api *gin.Engine) {
    r := api.Group("/v1")
    r.GET("/sites/search/:url", site.Search)
}
```

In the controller file, want to use [go-elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch) for searching ES data.

```
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/myapp/common/elasticsearch"
)

func Search(ctx *gin.Context) {
   var data bool
   data = GetES(ctx.Request.Context()) 
}

func GetES(ctx context.Context) bool {
    var (
        r   map[string]interface{}
        buf bytes.Buffer
    )

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    query := map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "match": map[string]interface{}{
                "title": "test",
            },
        },
    }
    if err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(query); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error encoding query: %s", err)
    }


    res, err := elasticsearch.ESClient.Search(
        elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithContext(ctx),
        elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithIndex("indexname"),
        elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithBody(&buf),
        elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
    )
    // ...
}
```

The current `go-elasticsearch`'s initialize method is using `ctx context.Context` in a common file:

```
import (
    "context"
    elasticsearch "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/esapi"
)

func Init(ctx context.Context) {
    var (
        ESClient = *elasticsearch.Client
    )
    // ...
    res, err := esapi.InfoRequest{}.Do(ctx, ESClient)
    // ...
}
```

If use `req *http.Request` in the controller `Search` function, it's possible to call data successfully. But gin's `ctx *gin.Context` will cause error:

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:199 (0x44470b)
    panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:394 (0x444548)
    sigpanic: panicmem()
/application/site/controller.go:100 (0xe9afea)
    GetES: elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithContext(ctx),
/application/site/controller.go:77 (0xe9a8a4)
    Search: data = GetES(ctx.Request.Context())
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/app/service/console/application/golang/console-api/application/auth/authenticate.go:16 (0xb90f7a)
    APIKeyAuthenticate.func1: ctx.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/app/service/console/application/golang/console-api/application/error/error_handler.go:13 (0xb3c60e)
    Handle500.func1: ctx.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/app/service/console/application/golang/console-api/application/error/error_handler.go:27 (0xb3c84f)
    Handle400.func1: ctx.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/recovery.go:83 (0x99bad3)
    RecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/logger.go:241 (0x99ac00)
    LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/context.go:161 (0x987fda)
    (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:409 (0x991f1c)
    (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.6.3/gin.go:367 (0x99161d)
    (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2802 (0x6dc303)
    serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1890 (0x6d7ba4)
    (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 (0x45d300)
    goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

I also tried to use `ctx *gin.Context` in the `GetES` function

```
func GetES(ctx *gin.Context) bool {
```

or set `context.Background()` in the ES's search method:

```
elasticsearch.ESClient.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
```

Still got the error.

How to use `gin` with `go-elasticsearch` together with a suitable `Context` type?

What content it needs in this method?

https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/master/_examples/main.go#L127

Answer (score 0):

`*gin.Context` is different from the context asked by `go-elasticsearch`, if you have search terms in `*gin.Context`, you can get them and query them using a function like `search()`.

```
 package main
    
    import (
        "bytes"
        "context"
        "encoding/json"
        es "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch"
        api "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/esapi"
        app "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "strings"
    )
    
    var c *es.Client
    
    func init() {
        // connect to elastic search client
        cf := es.Config{
            Addresses: []string{
                "http://localhost:9200",
            },
        }
        e, err := es.NewClient(cf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        c = e
        // make a new index
        // put some new data
        // search database for data
    }
    
    
    
    func search(term string, key string) (by []byte, err error) {
        q := map[string]interface{}{
            "query": map[string]interface{}{
                "match": map[string]interface{}{
                    key: term},
            },
        }
        var bts bytes.Buffer
        if err = json.NewEncoder(&bts).Encode(q); err != nil {
            return
        }
        r, err := c.Search(
            c.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
            c.Search.WithIndex("test"),
            c.Search.WithBody(&bts),
            c.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
            c.Search.WithPretty(),
        )
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer r.Body.Close()
        by, err = ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil || r.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
            return
        }
        return
    }
    
    func handlerr(a interface{}, err error) {
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("%s", a)
    }
    func main() {
        r:=app.Default()
        r.GET("/",GetES)
        r.Run(":8080")
        return
    }
      
    
     func GetES(c *gin.Context){
       res, err := search("my experiments with truth", "title")
       handlerr(res,err)
       c.JSON{http.StatusOK,res}
       return
     }
```